# Reciprocal of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am working with an expression of the form
$$ \frac{x^TAx}{{x^TBx}}$$
and would like to simplify it. I understand that vectors do not have inverses, but viewing the bottom number as a 1 by 1 matrix,
$$ \frac{x^TAx}{{x^TBx}} = (x^TAx)(x^TBx)^{-1} "=" (x^TAx)(x^{-1}B^{-1}x^{-T}) "=" x^TAB^{-1}x^{-T}. $$
Can I do something like this, but more formally?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to is not possible as inverse is defined only for matrices and not vectors. But, if you want to simplify your expression, we can do it in the following manner. But we need the assumption that $B^{-1}$ exists. Also, wlog, we can assume that $B$ is symmetric. Then, $$B=UDU^{T}=UD^{1/2}U^{T}UD^{1/2}U^{T}=B^{1/2}B^{1/2}$$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the non-zero eigenvalues and $U$ is a orthogonal matrix containing the eigenvectors of $B$. Then define $y=B^{1/2}x$ and then you have
$$\frac{x^TAx}{x^TBx}=\frac{y^T(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})y}{y^Ty}$$
This becomes the so-called Rayleigh-ratio of the matrix $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ and you have the identity that 
$$\lambda_{min}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})\leq \frac{y^T(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})y}{y^Ty} \leq \lambda_{max}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})$$

Comment: Do you think the best hope for finding the gradient of this function would be explicitly computing partials then?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do with it,,, add that also to the question

Comment: You cannot take the square root of a symmetric matrix in general unless it is positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible this way. Consider the matrices:

$$A = B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and $x=(1,1)^t$.

Then $AB^{-1} = I$

Therefore $$\frac{x^t A x}{x^t B x} = 1 \neq 2 = x^t AB^{-1} x $$

The thing to notice here is that $\frac{x^t A x}{x^t B x} $ is a *rational* function in $x$, and in general rational functions are very unlikely to be polynomial.

Comment: Do you think the best hope for finding the gradient of this function would be explicitly computing partials then?

Comment: That is an entirely different question. But you can use the standard differentiation rule for quotients.